# " is " returns False even if strings are same in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I was checking whether given is a palindrome or not.
This is a similar code to explain the nuances,

```
string = "radar"
new = string[::-1]
print (new)
print (string is new)
print (string in new)
print (string == new)
```

##### Output of above is:

```
radar
False
True
True
```

In all these conditionals statements I was expecting output to be `True` but `is` returns `False` even though words are same. Don't know why this keeps happening.

Comment: `is` is not qualified to compare strings. Use `==` instead.

Comment: `is` checks for object identity. You have two different objects with the same value.

Comment: "the same" and "equal" are two different things. They can represent identical values without being the same object.